# How do I change the default format of a shape (drawing object) in Impress

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice

When I create a new rectangle from the Drawing toolbar in OpenOffice Impress 3.4.1, it has really ugly formatting (line color, line width, and fill color).  I believe I inadvertently changed the default formatting for the shape.  How do I change the formatting to a style I like better?

FWIW, the way to do it in PowerPoint is to right-click on an object whose format you like and select "Set as Default Shape".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Ubuntu, Libre Office 6.2.4. In order to change the (default) style of existing objects:

1. Display styles (F11 or Format/Styles/Manage styles...)
2. Select the shape
3. **Double click** the new style to be set on the shape

I believe that a single click instead of the double would be much more intuitive and in my opinion the current behavior has to be a bug... Anyway, that's what worked for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using LibreOffice 4.4 but I believe I've done this on other version.

With nothing selected go to `Format` menu and set your preferences, or use the toolbar, reopening Impress will revert to default.

If you want something more permanent go to `Format > Styles & Formatting [F11]` and set your preferences to the `Default` style.